# Jenkins: how to invoke a post build action multiple times inside the same job?

Tags: jenkins, post-build

I am using this plugin: https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/docs/integrating-jenkins-ibm-urbancode-deploy/

Is there a way to push to multiple components in UCD from inside one Jenkins job? e.g. The same Jenkins project compiles Java and produce three components: app1_web, app1_ear, app1_db in UCD. I see the plugin inside the Post Build Action can only be inserted once in the same job. Guess this is a question in Jenkins.

Comment: I think you can create as many post jobs you need you can in jenkins. at the bottom of your job you will get post job and you can add there

Comment: @Aniruddha Das, after I add once, the entry will be grayed out so can't do that anymore. This is where the question comes from.

Comment: I jenkins you can modify any job as many time you want and add as much post job execute as you want. might be the problem is with IBM tool in which you are using jenmins. any scrsnshot or code?

Comment: @Aniruddha Das, e.g. you add the Email Notification in your post build step. After that you want to add another Email Notification entry, you can't. At this point, the Email Notification entry is gray out, you can't select that anymore.

Comment: ohh, got it. my mistake. I did something else by executing shell command! this is something different.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) rather than the old Freestyle job type, you can use post-build actions multiple times.

Though I don't know which plugin you're using, and whether it supports Pipeline.